# How can i center textviews in a table row that is constantly being generated dynamically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a zone list. And my function creates a table row for each zone and adds a textview of zone's name to this row and then adds this row to my TableLayout. Since the zonelist is populated from a database, the list may change during the lifetime of app.
What I'm trying to do is to center each textview in each row horizontally. I'm checking every source and people keep saying "add this piece of code to your XML file...". Since I'm creating these rows and textviews dynamically, I don't have any objects to manipulate in my XML file. So I have to somehow manage it by coding in Java side. Any help would be appriciated.

```
private void addTextView(final Zone zone) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(DashboardFragment.this.getActivity());
        TextView textView = new TextView(DashboardFragment.this.getActivity());
        textView.setId(zone.getId());
        textView.setText(zone.getName());
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        TextView seperator = new TextView(DashboardFragment.this.getActivity());
        seperator.setText("_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________");
        seperator.setTextSize(25);
        seperator.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        TableRow seperate = new TableRow(DashboardFragment.this.getActivity());
        seperate.addView(seperator);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), ZoneContentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("zone",zone);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        row.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(row);
        layout.addView(seperate);
    }
```

(Note: I know the way I seperate is not the best xD. So any help on this side would be appriciated as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In layout folder, (layout_row.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <include layout="@layout/line_horizontal_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

And for adding Row to table layout:

```
private void addRow(final Zone zone){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TableRow rowView = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);

        TextView textView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        textView.setText(zone.getName());
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setTextSize(25);

        layout.addView(rowView);
    }
```

Seperator is added on the layout_row. Hope it might help.

line_horizontal_gray.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for. Appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this line, all the rows come as empty rows